# Позиционирование div блоков и bootstrap контейнера

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, position

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как решить проблему с позиционированием:
есть блок меню и блок гугл карты,[image: на данный момент]
как позиционировать блок с картой, что бы он был под меню.

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top-line">
      <div class="row">
        menu
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  content
</div>
```

[image: результат]

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не совсем понятен. Возможно помогут `display: block; overflow:hidden; clear:both;`.
Если имеется ввиду наложение, то `position:absolute; position:relative; z-index:9999;`

Comment: Да, думаю position ближе к сути, когда блок меню имеет absolute, он выходит за пределы контейнера